# Query an array in MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I have this collection in MongoDB:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5df013b10a88910018267a89"), 
    "StockNo" : "33598", 
    "Description" : "some description", 
    "detections" : [
        {
            "lastDetectedOn" : ISODate("2020-01-29T04:36:41.191+0000"), 
            "lastDetectedBy" : "comp-t", 
            "_id" : ObjectId("5e3135f68c9e930017de8aec")
        }, 
        {
            "lastDetectedOn" : ISODate("2019-12-21T18:12:06.571+0000"), 
            "lastDetectedBy" : "comp-n", 
            "_id" : ObjectId("5e3135f68c9e930017de8ae9")
        }, 
        {
            "lastDetectedOn" : ISODate("2020-01-29T07:36:06.910+0000"), 
            "lastDetectedBy" : "comp-a", 
            "_id" : ObjectId("5e3135f68c9e930017de8ae7")
        }
    ], 
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2019-12-10T21:52:49.788+0000"), 
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2020-01-29T07:36:22.950+0000"), 
    "__v" : NumberInt(0)
}
```

I want to search by StockNo and get the name of the computer that last detected it (lastDetectedBy) only if lastDetectedOn was in the last 5 minutes with Mongoose in node.js with Express.

I also have this collection:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5df113b10d35670018267a89"), 
    "InvoiceNo" : "1", 
    "InvoiceDate" : ISODate("2020-01-14T02:18:11.196+0000"),
    "InvoiceContact : "",
    "isActive" : true
},
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5df013c90a88910018267a8a"), 
    "InvoiceNo" : "2", 
    "InvoiceDate" : ISODate("2020-01-14T02:18:44.279+0000"),
    "InvoiceContact : "Bob Smith",
    "isActive" : true
},
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e3096bb8c9e930017dc6e20"), 
    "InvoiceNo" : "3", 
    "InvoiceDate" : ISODate("2020-01-14T02:19:50.155+0000"),
    "InvoiceContact : "",
    "isActive" : true
}
```

And I want to update all the documents with empty InvoiceContact which has been issued in the last 30 seconds (or any date range between now and sometime in the past) with isActive equals true to isActive equals false. So for example, the first record has been issued in the last 30 seconds without InvoiceContact and isActive is true so this must be updated but the next two records will remain untouched for different reasons, the second record has InvoiceContact and the third record is out of range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First Part

```
 var mins5 = new Date(ISODate() - 1000* 60 * 5 )

 db.getCollection('user').find({$and:[
     { "StockNo":"33598"},
     {"detections.lastDetectedOn" : { $gte : mins5 }}
     ]})
     .map(function(list){
         var results = [];
         list.detections.forEach(function (detections){
             if(detections.lastDetectedOn > mins5){
                 results.push(detections.lastDetectedBy);
             }
         })
         return results;
     });
```

Second Part could be solved by a similar query using update instead of find.